# Regular expressions for Google operators

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP, I'm trying to improve the search on my site by supporting Google like operators e.g.

- keyword = natural/default
- "keyword" or "search phrase" = exact match
- keyword* = partial match

For this to work I need to to split the string into two arrays. One for the exact words (but  without the double quotes) into $Array1() and put everything else (natural and partial keywords) into Array2().

What regular expressions would achieve this for the following string?

---

**Example string ($string)**

> today i'm "trying" out a* "google search" "test"

**Desired result**

```
$Array1 = array(
  [0]=>trying
  [1]=>google search
  [2]=>testing
);

$Array2 = array(
  [0]=>today
  [1]=>i'm
  [2]=>out
  [3]=>a*
);
```

---

**1) Exact** I've tried the following for the exact regexp but it returns two arrays, one with and one without the double quotes. I could just use $result[1] but there could be a trick that I'm missing here.

```
preg_match_all(
    '/"([^"]+)"/iu', 
    'today i\'m "trying" \'out\' a* "google search" "test"', 
    $result
);
```

**2) Natural/Partial** The following rule returns the correct keywords, but along with several blank values. This regexp rule maybe sloppy or should I just run the array through array_filter()?

```
preg_split(
    '/"([^"]+)"|(\s)/iu', 
    'today i\'m "trying" \'out\' a* "google search" "test"'
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok) to tokenize the string.

See for example this `tokenizeQuoted` function derived from this [`tokenizedQuoted` function in the comments on the `strtok` manual page](http://docs.php.net/strtok#53244):

```
// split a string into an array of space-delimited tokens, taking double-quoted and single-quoted strings into account
function tokenizeQuoted($string, $quotationMarks='"\'') {
    $tokens = array(array(),array());
    for ($nextToken=strtok($string, ' '); $nextToken!==false; $nextToken=strtok(' ')) {
        if (strpos($quotationMarks, $nextToken[0]) !== false) {
            if (strpos($quotationMarks, $nextToken[strlen($nextToken)-1]) !== false) {
                $tokens[0][] = substr($nextToken, 1, -1);
            } else {
                $tokens[0][] = substr($nextToken, 1) . ' ' . strtok($nextToken[0]);
            }
        } else {
            $tokens[1][] = $nextToken;
        }
    }
    return $tokens;
}
```

Here’s an example of use:

```
$string = 'today i\'m "trying" out a* "google search" "test"';
var_dump(tokenizeQuoted($string));
```

The output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "trying"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "google search"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "today"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "i'm"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "out"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "a*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Gumbo, thank you! This works great for me. I wasn't aware of strtok() and it's a great solution.

Comment: This helped me out a bunch too. +1