# Intelligently parse user search terms in PHP

Tags: php, search-engine, text-parsing

I am in the midst of creating a search service for my PHP website and I was wondering how others have gone about intelligently parsing search terms based on quotation marks (and possibly other symbols in the future).

In others words, the search term **screwdriver hammer** might yield an array of ['screwdriver', 'hammer'], but **"flathead screedriver" hammer** might yield ['flathead screwdriver', 'hammer'].

I know I can accomplish this in a sloppy loop, but I'm sure PHP has something built in to handle this.

Comment: What are you doing with these keywords? Are you passing them on to mySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811519

Comment: I'm going to be translating them into an MSSQL (TSQL) database query. And I'm not duplicating. But thanks for the useful link :) if you'd have posted that as the answer, you would have won. Already implemented.

Comment: Does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **strtok** as per this [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811519)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Something like:

```
/* $search_term:
*  "flathead screwdriver" hammer -nails
*/

$terms = preg_split("/[\s]*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\"[\s]*|[\s]+/", $search_term);

/* $terms = array(
*      0    =>    "flathead screwdriver"
*      1    =>    "hammer"
*      2    =>    "-nails"
*/

$exclude = array();

foreach($terms as $term){
    if(strpos($term, '-') == 0)
        array_push($exclude, substr($term, 1));
}

/* $exclude = array(
*      0    =>    "nails"
*/
```

Only thing I didn't include is removing "nails" from the $terms array. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader =)