# explode string into tokens keeping quoted substr intact

Tags: php, regex

I dont know where I seen it, but can anyone tell me how to accomplish this using php and regex?

```
'this is a string "that has quoted text" inside.'
```

i want to be able to explode it like this

```
[0]this
[1]is
[2]a
[3]string
[4]"that has quoted text"
[5]inside
```

keeping the quotes intact.

Comment: would you ever have quotes inside the quoted string?  I assume not but just want to check...

Comment: no. Not if they want some results back. :-)

Comment: ok, see answer below.  It may need some tweaking but it at least works with your test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try following code:

```
$str = 'this is a string  "that has quoted text" inside.';
var_dump ( preg_split('#\s*("[^"]*")\s*|\s+#', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );

Output: 
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "this"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [4]=>
  string(22) ""that has quoted text""
  [5]=>
  string(7) "inside."
}
```

Here is the link for [above working code on dialpad](http://codepad.org/Dc87oia1)

### Update: For escaping support please try:

```
preg_split('#\s*((?<!\\\\)"[^"]*")\s*|\s+#', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Perhaps should be `[^"]*` rather than `[^"]+`?

Comment: Thanks @Hammerite for good suggestion, I edited the answer above to reflect the same.

Comment: @Hammerite @anubhava for some reason, when you put a quoted text at the beginning or end, it doesnt keep the quoted text intact inside the array.

Comment: @madphp You are right. I made some change in my answer above. Please try again. Basically new regex is `preg_split('#\s*("[^"]*")\s*|\s+#', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

Comment: @anubhava - can you think of way of keeping escaped strings intact ie http://pastebin.com/VLuJVnTq to this http://pastebin.com/zZjFZfh2

Comment: @madphp Please try: `preg_split('#\s*((?<!\\\\)"[^"]*")\s*|\s+#', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Can you please paste your original string that you tried to split?

Comment: @anubhava - search "this is a sentence" hello. This string is then espcaped search \"this is a sentence\" hello

Comment: @madphp That is being done by `var_dump` function, if you use `print_r` instead you will see `Array
(
    [0] => search
    [1] => "this is a sentence"
    [2] => hello
)`

Comment: @anubhava no, it was print_r. It should matter though. I want to preserve the back slashes inside the second array value.

Comment: I'm little confused because original string `search "this is a sentence" hello` didn't even have any back slash.

Answer (score 3):

Requires PHP >= 5.3.0

```
$str = 'this is a string "that has quoted text" inside';

$x = str_getcsv($str,' ','"');

var_dump($x);
```

This strips the quotes, but does leave the content of the quoted block intact.

Comment: Nice solution.  Very clever use of getcsv.  +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

This works on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) with your sample string:

`((".*?")|([\S]*))`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not necessarily need a regular expression, you could also use [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok) to tokenize the string. See this [`tokenizedQuoted` function in the comments on the `strtok` manual page](http://docs.php.net/strtok#53244) and [my enhancement of that `tokenizedQuoted` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811519/regular-expressions-for-google-operators/3811746#3811746) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

This requires lookback and look ahead stuff...

Try something like:

```
preg_split('/(?<!(".+)) (?!(.+"))/', $str, -1 ,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[not tested]

Comment: No lookback/ahead required as OP isn't supporting nested quotes (see comments).