# exploding string that do not have quote sign

Tags: php

I have string like `abc xyz "a x" test "test1 test2"` I want to split string with space but word inside quote should remain as it is. I can split string using explode but explode won't work here as per my requirement.

After exploding/spliting output should like

```
[0] => abc
[1] => xyz
[2] => "a x"
[3] => test
[4] => "test1 test2"
```

I think preg_split do for me but don't know proper regular expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [explode string into tokens keeping quoted substr intact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475312/explode-string-into-tokens-keeping-quoted-substr-intact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
$str = 'this is a string  "that has quoted text" inside.';

// #1 version
$arOne = preg_split('#\s*("[^"]*")\s*|\s+#', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// #2 version
$arTwo = preg_split('#\s*((?<!\\\\)"[^"]*")\s*|\s+#', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**Output**:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "this"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [4]=>
  string(22) ""that has quoted text""
  [5]=>
  string(7) "inside."
}
```

Taken from here: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475680/996809)

Answer (score 0):

Another good and simple answer is

```
$str = abc xyz "a x" test "test1 test2"
str_getcsv($str,' ','"');
```

will return an array for more detail about [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) 
which will return array splitted by space and without "

output of above

```
[0] => abc
[1] => xyz
[2] => a x
[3] => test
[4] => test1 test2
```